# Get __EVENTTARGET from web user control

Tags: asp.net

When I post back an ASP.NET page from a web user control, it does not give me any __EVENTTARGET details so I'm unable to determine which control caused the postback.

Is there a way to force the user control to report that it caused the postback?

Thanks

Nick

Answer (score 0):

In a word... no.  Why are you looking at __EVENTTARGET to begin with?  Obviously I haven't seen your code, but I can't think of any reason you'd want to do this that isn't a total hack.

Do you control the code for this user control?  The proper way (well, one of them) for a user control to communicate this sort of thing to its host Page is to expose events which the host can assign event handlers.